# Installing xmgrace on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu to do my research project and require xmgrace to plot my data. I did "sudo apt install grace" and then when I tried to plot the data with "xmgrace (file)", I was met with the error message "can't open display, failed initialising, exiting". I'm very new to this and some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyone in your school using this?  I did some looking around and xmgrace is 5 year old at least and for old Windows, and Uniix-like systems. It does not say Linux. Perhaps check around a bit and see if your associates are using anything different.

Comment: Thanks @John for your response! I'll try asking around. The only reason I'm using xmgrace is because I'm doing MD with GROMACS and the online tutorial says to use xmgrace as the plotting tool (http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/lysozyme/05_EM.html) but maybe these tutorials are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Your error sounds like it *could* be an X-forwarding issue. If you are ssh'ed into the machine on which xmgrace is installed, make sure you passed the -Y flag when ssh'ing in.

A few notes.

The tutorials that Justin Lemkul's lab setup are still some of the most comprehensive around. They are aging but Gromac's site still points to them and Lemkul, himself, is [easily contacted and open to bug fixes, suggestions, etc](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/lysozyme/11_summary.html).

I wouldn't discount xmgrace. It is a powerful 2D plotting tool that is capable of making publication-quality plots. It is easy to embed its .eps outputs into LaTeX documents. But there is a learning curve. And @John is right: development has probably [ceased](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3767).

Finally the .xvg files produced by gromacs are simple ascii text files so you can always just strip off the grace headers and any comments and plot with anything that can parse the evenly spaced columns.

Also keep in mind that, if you get xmgrace working on your linux machine, you might be tempted to start it

> xmgrace filename.xvg

But some of the data output by gromacs is multi-column. It is better often to launch xmgrace without the data filename, use import item from the data menu, and select NXY from the pulldown in the data-import dialog.